# Calling invalidateTags with a specific ID seems to also clear the cache for other IDs

Tags: rtk-query

I have the following endpoint which provides tags using the id argument:

```
getNewsletter: builder.query<NewsletterGetResult, number>({
        query: id => `/newsletter/${id}`,
        providesTags: (result: any, error: any, arg: number) => [
            {type: 'Newsletter', id: arg}
        ]
    })
```

Elsewhere in the code, I'm calling `invalidateTags` with an argument which matches the above endpoint's tags:

```
dispatch(newsletterApi.util.invalidateTags(invalidatePayload as any[]));
```

Finally, the above endpoint is used in a component:

```
useGetNewsletterQuery(Number.parseInt(id as string));
```

The problem is that calling `invalidateTags` with a specific ID appears to clear the cache for all IDs

Please see the screenshare below for an example of how this manifests itself in my app

https://www.loom.com/share/123e5638c8b94ba5912e15dee152caad?sid=e205ed20-000b-4fd1-9aba-0054647adae5

In the screenshare, the left side contains a component with ID 82679 while the right side contains the same component with ID 82725. The console output on the left side shows the argument passed to invalidateTags when a change is made to the component:

```
{type: 'Newsletter', id: 82679}
```

After this happens, a progress bar appears in the component on the right side of the screen, which indicates that the cache was cleared and the query re-ran (the progress bar only appears when the query's `isFetching` property returns true), even though the ID does not match that of the argument passed to invalidateTags.

Please let me know whether this is an actual issue or there's a gap in my understanding of the invalidateTags behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I misdiagnosed the issue. The arguments sent to invalidateTags included `'Newsletter'` as well as `{type: 'Newsletter', id: 82679}`. I was previously under the impression that passing a tag type without an ID would only affect endpoints which don't use IDs and therefore assumed that the endpoint in question, which contains

```
providesTags: (result: any, error: any, arg: number) => [
        {type: 'Newsletter', id: arg}
    ]
```

would be unaffected. But it appears that the type alone trumps the IDs.

Comment: Yes, for reference you can see this table: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching#tag-invalidation-behavior - the first two lines are the case you were running into